# How to MVVM bind Child to Child of same Parent?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have the following visual tree

```
MainWindow
  |--------UserControl
               |----------ChildListView1
  |--------ChildListView2
```

When user selects an item in ChildListView1, The ViewModel object of that item will be taken and it has a property called ConfigParams which has to be bound to ChildListView2.

Here is my view model

```
public class Equipment
{
  public string Name {get; set;} //TODO: Change to Raise PropertyChanged on set
  public ObservableCollection<ConfigParams> {get;set;}
}
```

Here is MainWindow's view model

```
public class MainViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<Equipment> Equipments {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Seems it should be easily doable by putting a `SelectedItem` property in the VM and Binding to that. What have you tried?

Comment: Does that involve any code to be written in some.xaml.cs ? I have not tried anything yet, just came up with first strategy that I am working on

Comment: No, you have to put a property in the ViewModel and bind to that.. anyways, why are you so scared of code behind? lol

Comment: is ChildListView2 a ViewModel ? or some usercontrol ?

Comment: A ListView control. I got it working. Posting my solution as answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the xaml.cs of my `UserControl` I added the following property

```
public ListView ListInstances { get { return ChildListView1; } }
```

Added the following `ItemsSource` binding to my `ChildListView2`

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ListInstances.SelectedItem.ConfigParams, ElementName=MyUserControlName}"
```